# How to close tab page on tabcontrol by tab page's name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

In c# how can I destroy a tab on a tab control by targeting it's name? I've a tab named "Hello!" and I'd like to close it programatically. There's no guarantee that it will be the selected tab at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TabControl` class provides a [`TabPages` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpages.aspx) that returns a [`TabPageCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.aspx) containing all of the `TabPages` in the control.

So you can use the [`Item` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/839bz4e1.aspx) to retrieve the `TabPage` with the specified name.

For example, if the tab page you want is named "Hello!", you would write:

```
var tabPage = myTabControl.TabPages["Hello!"];
```

To remove the `TabPage` from the control, use the [`RemoveByKey` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.removebykey.aspx):

```
myTabControl.TabPages.RemoveByKey("Hello!");
```

Of course, in order for this to work, you'll need to make sure that you've set the keys of your `TabPage`s to match the caption text they display.

Comment: that was quick, beat me to it!

Comment: Thank you Cody! Looking at LarsTech's answer, should I dispose it instead of remove it for memory's sake?

Comment: @atw I would do both, just to be on the safe side. Remove it first, then dispose it. But you can get away with just disposing it ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757116/remove-tabpage-dispose-or-clear-or-both)).

Comment: I've setup the solution but am setback: 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.TabPageCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.TabPageCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @atw Hmm, yeah `Item` is the default property in C#. My syntax is wrong. I've spent too long today looking at VB.NET code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
for (int i = tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (tabControl1.TabPages[i].Text == "Hello!")
    tabControl1.TabPages[i].Dispose();
}
```

I'm assuming you meant the "Text" of the TabPage, since "Hello!" wouldn't be a valid name for a control.

Note: this code will dispose of any TabPage that says "Hello!"

Comment: Is disposing a tabpage while it's still added to a tabcontrol a good idea?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I don't think there is any danger.  Removing it doesn't dispose of it, and the OP said he wanted it "destroyed".

Comment: @sambomartin Dispose() will remove it.  See [Hans Passant answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1970158/719186).

Comment: The clearer and more definitive answer to that question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757116/remove-tabpage-dispose-or-clear-or-both).